# WebApplicationContext in Spring.NET - Is it thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, .net, spring.net

I'm dealing with some tech debt on a web project I inherited.  Instead of using the context provided thru Spring.NET's WebContextHandler, I am instantiating the Spring application context programmatically, so I can consolidate multiple connection strings in this thing's numerous config files.

Right now, I have this instantiating once upon first use, using a singleton pattern.  Will this be fine for a web application, or do I need to initialize a new instance per web request?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find that class in the official Spring.NET API Documentation located [here](http://springframework.net/documentation.html) so I can't give you any definite answers.

But as Spring.NET is OpenSource I suggest you look at the source code of that class on their [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/blob/master/src/Spring/Spring.Web/Context/Support/WebApplicationContext.cs) and try to see whether they use some form of locking. I can't find anything like that in this class, so allthough I can't see any writes outside the constructors you probably should not rely on the thread safety here.
Actually nevermind: The [base class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/blob/master/src/Spring/Spring.Core/Context/Support/AbstractXmlApplicationContext.cs) and the [base class of that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/blob/master/src/Spring/Spring.Core/Context/Support/AbstractApplicationContext.cs) do lots of things which write to the object's state so the class is definitely not thread safe.

As I am not familiar with the Spring Framework I am not sure what you try to accomplish. Maybe you could wrap accesses to this object in your own lock-statements.

Other than that: How to use this class should be documented somewhere.

Also: While I was looking through the code of [AbstractApplicationContext](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/blob/master/src/Spring/Spring.Core/Context/Support/AbstractApplicationContext.cs) I found a property called SyncRoot. Whenever a class has a SyncRoot-property there has to be a synchronization mechanism somewhere.